# Tagged PDF How to move a PDSElement to another position in the PDSTreeRoot?

Tags: pdf, adobe, accessibility

I'm tagging a PDF's content with Adobe's PDF Lib. My logical Tree Structure `PDSTreeRoot` has several elements.

The top Element is called `Document`. I need to move all the other `PSDElements` under the `PSDEelement Document`. This is needed for creating accessible PDFs.

I can do it with Acrobat Pro (just shift-click mark all the Tag-Elements and move them under the Document-Tag) so I thought this has to be possible with the Adobe PDF Lib.

```
    ASInt32 numKids = PDSTreeRootGetNumKids (myTreeRoot);
    PDSElement  pdsDocElem, pdsElem;
    //First PDSElement is the Document-Element
    PDSTreeRootGetKid(myTreeRoot, 0, &pdsDocElem);


    for( int i2 = 1; i2 < numKids;i2++)
    {
        PDSTreeRootGetKid(myTreeRoot,i2,&pdsElem);
        PDSElementInsertKid(pdsDocElem,pdsElem,kPDSAfterLast);
    }
```

The last line throws the following error:

> Error code: 1074855939: Wrong type parameter supplied to a PDS procedure

Any help?

Comment: Does it throw that error immediately? Or only after some iterations? I don't know exactly how this tree here works, but you're counting the number of elements in the PDSTreeRoot and then in a loop you're starting to moving stuff from the PDSTreeRoot array into another element; effectively removing it from the PDSTreeRoot object I would guess... Aren't you undermining your own counting scheme?

Comment: THanks for your answer Ryan. You are describing a problem I didnt think about! But the error gets thrown on first call :(